# Zoom/Scale CWnd Controls in Visual C++

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

We've got a CWnd that has several controls (CButton, CEdit, CStatic, etc) on it and would like to find a way to allow the user to zoom in and out such that the controls get larger/smaller.  The control itself needs to change size as well as the text labels inside the controls (like the button text).

I was looking into the CZoomView documented on the web and using the CDC SetMapMode to MM_ISOTROPIC, but this seems to really only be useful in an OnDraw method since the CZoomView has a TODO to implement drawing code when implemented.  Since these are Microsoft controls, we're just letting them draw themselves.

Is this even possible?  It seems like I should be able to use the adjust the device context to think that the device to logical unit scale is different, but I can't come up with how to get the controls to honor this.

```
int previousMode = pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ISOTROPIC);
CSize previousWin = pDC->SetWindowExt(100,100);
CSize previousExt = pDC->SetViewportExt(m_zoom, m_zoom);
```

Thoughts or ideas?

Comment: But why do you need to "zoom" a control?

Comment: Think about how you have the ability to change the zoom in a web browser on a web page with a form like this page.  When you zoom, it changes the size of all the text and controls in the same scale.  We were looking for a way to do this in a CWnd, but it doesn't appear to be doable.  Anyway, I've moved away from that project now, so it's not on my plate any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible with Win32 user/standard/common controls because the "User32" layer of Windows is all based on pixels and the GDI functions you mention do not work at that level, and there is no equivalent in the User API (window handles vs device contexts).

---

I know this is an old question and I'm not answering to get points.  I was going to ask this same question myself, but then came across this after I finished typing my question.  Since you aren't supposed to ask duplicate questions here, I'm posting this answer instead hoping that someone will come along and prove me wrong with a better answer.  Or possibly Mark figured out the answer and will get notified of my answer and share what he learned.  In my case I need to make a UI like Adobe Acrobat with fill-able forms, but the basics are the same.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I never did find a good solution for it and I don't think there is a way for the exact reasons you mentioned.  If someone else finds a way, they can provide their answer, but for now I'm going to accept your answer since I agree.

Comment: This is definitely not possible with MFC but very easy to achieve in Qt without even coding.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the DPI setting in Windows (Display -> Set custom text size)? That's the common way of making things smaller/larger and users are expected to do this if they have trouble reading stuff.

Windows standard controls are "DPI aware" so you get the zooming for free.

Comment: This is an option for each user if they want to affect all of their applications.  We need to make this specific form zoomable separately from the global DPI setting.  It's a long story...